# Can the word "there" be used as noun?

Tags: word-usage

Dictionary say "here" is adverb and "there" is adverb and noun.

How can the word "there" be used as noun? Can't the word "here" be used as noun?

In addition, now I knew that "there" is used as pronoun like " There is a pen.". If so, how about "Here is"?

Comment: For example: hi there! ..... There is no "hi here!" :p

Comment: Is it only the case?

Comment: Thefreedictionary.com will help you with *here* and *there*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words here and there can be used as nouns to mean "this place/point" and "that place/point" correspondingly.  For examples:

The restaurant is two miles away from here/there.

Get away from here/there.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I checked it again in dictionary, so "here" is pronominally used like your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can say:

> Here is a pen.

Think of giving a pen to someone right in front of you.

On the other hand:

> There is a pen.

The pen does not have a specific location.

Comment: This is not a good answer.  In the abstract sentence "there is a pen", as in "somewhere in this room there is a pen", the pen has no specific location.  But if you see a pen and point to it, "there is a pen", the pen does have a specific location.

Comment: That is true, Paul. I didn't think of it that way.